# generator for boost::fusion::map initialization with noncopyable value type

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, fusion

I'd like to create a base class which is able to contain N sockets. These are ZeroMQ sockets, and they are not copyable. In that case base class can generically implement shutdown behaviour on managed sockets and other service functions. Whereas derived classes can access the required socket using the tag type.

My idea was to use `boost::fusion::map`. Socket types are not default constructible thus I need to pass as parameters: reference to context and int identifying the socket type (`ZMQ_{SOCKET_TYPE}` which is `int`). Finally, there should be a generator function to create a `socket_t` to be placed in `fusion::map`. The idea is to use `fusion::repetitive_view` right now, as sockets have all the same initialization params.

Problem right now, is that: if I manually pass `socket_t{context, int}, socket_t{context, int}` instances to the `fusion::map` ctor everything just works fine. Using the generator results in compilation stating that `socket_t` is not copyable.

Here is the simplified code I am trying to compile:

```
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/pair.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container/generation/make_vector.hpp>


using namespace std;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
namespace fus = boost::fusion;

struct context_t : boost::noncopyable
{};

struct socket_t : boost::noncopyable
{
  socket_t(context_t& context, int type) : context_{&context}, type_{type}
  {}

  socket_t(socket_t&& s) : context_{s.context_}, type_{s.type_}
  {}

  socket_t& operator=(socket_t&& s)
  {
    context_ = s.context_;
    type_ = s.type_;
    return *this;
  }

  void use_fields()const
  { // just to avoid warnings that fields are not used
    (void)context_;
    (void)type_;
  }

private:
  context_t* context_;
  int type_;
};

// we need a view of keys in conjunction with the context
template<class T>
auto infinite_context(fus::vector<T> v)
{
  return fus::repetitive_view<fus::vector<T>>{v};
}


template<class... Pairs>
struct base_type
{
  typedef fus::map<Pairs...> tagged_map;

  base_type() : context_{} //, sockets_{}
  {}

  context_t context_;
  //fus::map<Pairs...> sockets_;
};

struct tag1 {};
struct tag2 {};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  context_t c;

  typedef base_type<fus::pair<tag1, socket_t>, fus::pair<tag2, socket_t>> test_me_type;


  auto g = infinite_context(fus::make_vector([&c]()->socket_t{ return {c, 1}; }));

  test_me_type::tagged_map m1{socket_t{c, 1}, socket_t{c, 1}}; //OK
  //test_me_type::tagged_map m2{g}; //Error: access to deleted copy ctor!

  (void)g;
  (void)m1;
  //(void)m2;

  return 0;
}
```

IMO the issue is that, `fusion::vector` instance used in `fusion::repetitive_view` becomes not copyable... Thus no generation possible. How is it possible to generate and forward N `socket_t` instances to the `fusion::map`?

Comment: The declaration `auto infinite_context(fus::vector<T> v)` would require to copy the vector. Would it help to change it to `auto infinite_context(fus::vector<T> & v)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am right now on that path as well, trying to introduce a proxy object with implicit `operator socket_t();`. So that it always generates a new r-value on-demand, but can be copied until its final destination and still have errors blaming copy construction.

Comment: Yes, I guess the result of the function returned by value still requires a copy constructor to be available (although usually RVO will be in place). Maybe also take a look on `boost::ref`, perhaps it could help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK solved it.

The key was to introduce a copyable proxy object which has implicit conversion operator to  `fusion::pair<TagType, socket_t>`. The missing snippet is:

```
struct convertible
{
  convertible(context_t& c, int t)
    : c_{&c}
    , t_{t}
  {}

  template<class Tag>
  operator fus::pair<Tag, socket_t>()const
  {
    return socket_t{*c_, t_};
  }

private:
  context_t* c_;
  int t_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  context_t c;

  typedef base_type<fus::pair<tag1, socket_t>, fus::pair<tag2, socket_t>> test_me_type;

  auto g = infinite_context(fus::make_vector(convertible{c, 1}));

  test_me_type::tagged_map m1{socket_t{c, 1}, socket_t{c, 1}}; //OK
  test_me_type::tagged_map m2{g}; //OK as well!


  (void)g;
  (void)m1;
  (void)m2;

  return 0;
}
```